# apply on dataframe works for one row, but apply over multiple rows fails for that particular row

Tags: r, apply

Apply on dataframe works for one row, but apply over multiple rows fails for that particular row
Here's an example (row 954 works in isolation):

```
     apply(dx[954,], 1, query.db)
            2571
1092  0.06044147
3890  0.05948577
3273  0.05911261
794   0.05855583
4241  0.05854064
3560  0.05602690
```

But when it's combined with one or more of the rest of the rows in the data.frame, row 954 returns numeric(0):

```
 apply(dx[954:955,], 1, query.db)
$`2571`
numeric(0)

$`1194`
         908         3754         5119         2835         3139         2775
 0.028935504  0.026941886  0.024762815  0.023335049  0.021892711  0.021001654
        1101         1762          401         3899         3727         4248
 0.020434257  0.020413724 -0.083333333  0.020111260  0.019872379  0.019840807
        3282         4585          798         5249          836         3570
 0.019729315  0.019524213  0.019440097  0.019410513  0.019288864  0.019052412
         726         3663         4775         3030         4938         3259
 0.018894556  0.018838258  0.018749506 -0.083333333  0.018416353  0.018240173
        1426         4563         3871          958         1242         1033
```

Here are the functions I'm using (please forgive the <<-, needed access to those variables in separate functions! Any suggestions on re-writing that are welcome! You can see my attempt at re-writing an an-line function which did not work and is commented out.

```
query.db <- function(dxdf){
    snquery = dbSendQuery(connection, paste("select distinct cpt4code from DxRxLookup where icd9code = '", dxdf[4], "'", sep = ""))
    cptcodes <<- dbGetResult(snquery)
    if(dim(cptcodes)[1] == 0){
        return (0)
    }

    #restrict this to constrain by Rx1 and Rx2 inputs
    h1 <- which(cpt$Cpt %in% cptcodes[,1])
    y <- which((cpt$Rx2 %in% dxdf[2] | cpt$Rx1 %in% dxdf[2]) & (cpt$Rx1 %in% dxdf[3] | cpt$Rx2 %in% dxdf[3]))
    hits <- intersect(y, h1)

    sum.all.hits <<- sum(cpt[hits,]$Log.Odds.Ratio)
    miss <<- 1 / (length(y) - length(hits))
#   apply(cpt[y,], 1, function(cptdf) if (cptdf[4] %in% codes[,1]){ P.hit <- as.numeric(cptdf[6]) / sum.of.hits; return (P.hit)} else { return (-m)}, c(codes=cptcodes, sum.of.hits=sum.all.hits, m=miss))
    apply(cpt[y,], 1, calc.enrichment)

}
```

Comment: you'll have better luck getting your question answered if you post a minimal, reproducible example that shows your problem. Posting the  actual data-frame would be a start.

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you start to debug, you'll find that the <<- is causing the problem. There's no way on earth we can help you without data or any idea about what you're trying to do, but if it works for one row and not for many, there must be communication between the different rows. And that communication is likely happening through the global environment. So I guess a dangerous habit is biting you badly.

Comment: yes, I'm guessing that the global scoping is the problem. Any suggestions as to how to access variables from one function in another? I essentially need to do an apply within an apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your SQL query returns what you would like? Numeric(0) suggest that you retrieve an empty resultset. Furthermore, as pointed by @Prasad Chalasani, try to post a more precise problem description. From the above I am not sure I understand what your aim is.

Comment: Furthermore, the error might in fact be in the SQL query which I am in know way able to check for correctness.

Comment: @Christian I agree the downvote is a bit harsh, but your answer should have been a comment. Somebody believed it was not helpful (as an answer).

Comment: @Joris Meys I agree on that, however, I can't figure out how to comment on the posed questions. I can easily comment on answer suggestions, though. I thought it had something to do with rank, but perhaps I just need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Christian : ah, I just saw the problem : you don't have enough reputation for commenting, you need at least 50 (see the FAQ) Very harsh downvote then, as you simply can't comment. Which is solved now.

Comment: @Joris Meys Nice to be able to comment now, rather than just obtaining down votes :-)

Comment: Yes I am sure the SQL is ok. The global scoping is most likely the issue. I need to determine a way to do an apply within an apply while being able to access the variables derived in the parent apply from the child apply. I tried writing a user defined function within the apply but the arguments I was passing were not being identified properly.